# sql запрос не работает в python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

[image: таблица count]

[image: значения]

при попытке вернуть значение з этой таблицы вообще возвращается назва колоны в виде строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в данном примере я хочу взять количество `users` но почемуто возвращаеться строка з назвой колоны

```
from baseclasses import DbBase



class BasicQuery(DbBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("library.db")

    def get_user_count(self) -> int:
        return self.__get_count("users")

    def get_book_count(self) -> int:
        return self.__get_count("book")

    def get_lease_count(self) -> int:
        return self.__get_count("lease")

    def __get_count(self, counter) -> int:
        with self._connect:
            result = self._cursor.execute("select ? from count ", (counter,)).fetchall()
            self._connect.commit()

    def __exit(self):
        super().__exit__()
```

Comment: Не вижу смысла в `select ? `, зачем вам делать запрос, указывая чтобы вам вернулось значение переменной `counter`

Comment: Это запрос для получения всех данных из таблицы: `result = self._cursor.execute("select * from count").fetchall()`

Comment: но мне нужен только отдельная колона , коротуя я передаю в функциях

Comment: Мне интересно почему вообще возвращаеться назва колоны в виде строки

Comment: должно было бы вернуться как минимум ```NoneType```

Comment: Из кода этого вроде не следует, но у меня впечатление, что у вас подставляется строка вместе с кавычками. Возможно, `cursor.execute` сам так делает по умолчанию - подставляет строки с кавычками.

Comment: ```result = self._cursor.execute("select '?' from count ", (counter,)).fetchall()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.``` неработает взятие в кавычки

Comment: Пишите с @<ник> :) Попробуйте так: `result = self._cursor.execute(f"select {counter} from count").fetchall()`, чтобы при составлении запроса указать его столбец

Comment: ой нет , ето вобще не работает

Comment: я уже много чего попробовал

Comment: @andriy-byte Как именно не работает вариант предложенный @gil9red? У вас мне кажется лишние кавычки получаются, а не недостающие, его вариант должен это починить. Хотя это только предположение.

Comment: интерполяция sqlite запроса неработает , я весь проект переписал изза етого

Comment: @andriy-byte Питон старой версии? Ну можно же тупо вместо интерполяции строки сложить `"select " + counter + " from count"`

Comment: даже в документации написано , еслиб знал што так будет то лутше бы написал на постгрессе

Comment: Как это?! Это же просто строка, которая передаётся в функцию как есть, как она может не работать? Напечатайте на экран какая строка получается. Попробуйте эту строку "вручную" выполнить на базе.